# ASP.NET MVC 5 : show details of logged in user

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to display user profile only for current logged in user, so that means user supposedly cannot see the profile for other user. But when I use the code below, it shows details for all registered users.

```
public ActionResult ShowDetail()
{
    var items = context.CustomerAccounts;
    return View(items.ToList());
}
```

I tried to add code suggested below but it only return the table header(name, dob, etc).

Can someone help me? TQ

Answer (score 0):

you can use User.Identity.Name to access username of logged in user. depends on your class you can do something like this:

```
public ActionResult ShowDetail()
{
    var items = context.CustomerAccounts.Where(c=>c.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
    return View(items.ToList());
}
```

Comment: Hi, when I apply your code above, the page only display table user header.

Comment: you have to replace User.Identity.Name with logged in user name